# Obtener datos con eloquent whereNotNull con laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy tratando de hacer un query en mi api, para el momento de que el usuario actualiza su correo electronico.
busca que no exista un correo igual omitiendo el suyo... no me arroja nada, solo me arroja un arreglo vacio  [ ]

```
isset_user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->where('id', '!=', $id)->whereNotNull('deleted_at')->toSql();
```

coloque el `toSql()` para que me muestre como esta enviando el query y lo hace de la siguiente manera

```
select * from `users` where `email` = ? and `id` != ? and `deleted_at` is not null and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
```

no entiendo por que manda doble vez, la consulta del `and deleted_at is not null and users.deleted_at is null`

alguien me puede orientar en como hacer correctamente el query o el por que me esta haciendo el query de esa manera

Answer (score 3):

Supongamos que tienes una tabla con esta estructura.

```
+----+---------+-------------------+
| ID | Usuario |      Correo       |
+----+---------+-------------------+
|  1 | Juanito | juanito@gmail.com |
|  2 | José    | jose@gmail.com    |
+----+---------+-------------------+
```

Si estás logueado como Juanito, y generas una consulta para un usuario con un ID diferente al tuyo y un correo igual al tuyo... sencillamente no habrá resultados. Sin embargo, si intentas cambiar tu correo a `jose@gmail.com` la consulta regresará como resultado la fila con ID `2`.

Ahora, el SQL generado tiene dos cláusulas `where` que hacen referencia a la columna `deleted_at` **porque estás usando la funcionalidad `SoftDeletes`** que viene con Laravel, **la cual automáticamente añade las condiciones necesarias a tus consultas para no recuperar filas "borradas".**

Es importante recalcar que en tu consulta estás especificando que se deben recuperar las filas borradas `->whereNotNull('deleted_at')`, lo cual genera conflicto con el comportamiento default de `SoftDeletes`.

Comment: Le dejamos también el enlace de la doc: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting para que el OP vaya profundizando mas :)

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta anterior, y segun entiendo al usarn `whereNotNull('deleted_at')` estas intentando obtener los registros eleminados, para esto laravel tiene una solución

Puedes usar el metodo `onlyTrashed()`, intentalo asi:

```
isset_user = User::onlyTrashed()->where('email', '=', $email)->where('id', '!=', $id)->toSql();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models